# css/php making images into hyper-references

Tags: php, html

I get confused mixing css and php. I have this html code

```
<li>
        <a href="www.me.com" class="reverse alternate01" title="my product title from a variable goes here.">
            <img src="img_sunrise.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
```

I have this code too in php

```
<a href="product-detail.php?product_id=<?php echo $row1['product_id'];?>&pagename=<?php echo $page_id;?>"><?php echo $image; ?></a>
```

Now, I want to put the second[php] code into the first one. The title attribute too should be dynamic. That is i want to assign title to $title which i get from a database. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify how we can help?

Comment: This isn't really a how-to problem but more of a writing the actual code problem. Is there anything specifically about creating dynamic html that you are having trouble with?

Comment: here's a tip:  If you don't include a **?** in your _question_, your _question_ probably needs some revision.  Snarky comments aside, Are you asking how to print variables in your HTML?  The HTML would have to be parsed through PHP in order to read the variables in.

Comment: Retagged, nothing to do with css for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Its not very clear, what you are asking. But before this question gets closed, I will try my best to at least give you some ideas.

**This is not in so much php, but in html:**

```
<a href="product-detail.php?product_id=<?php echo $row1['product_id'];?>&pagename=<?php echo $page_id;?>"><?php echo $image; ?></a>
```

**This is more in php then in html:**

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="product-detail.php?product_id=' . $row1['product_id'] . '&pagename=' . $page_id . '">' . $image . '</a>';
?>
```

Now, I'm gonna try my luck to answer your question:

```
$products[] = array(
    'domain' => 'http://www.me.com',
    'title' => 'my product title from a variable goes here.',
    'image' => 'img_sunrise.jpg'
);
$products[] = array(
    'domain' => 'http://www.iyfgaming.com',
    'title' => 'sells crack',
    'image' => 'crack.png'
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . $product['domain'] . '" class="reverse alternate01" title="' . $product['title'] . '"><img src="' . $product['image'] . '" /></a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**NOTES**

- `href="www.me.com"` is incorrect. Correct would be: `href="http://www.me.com"`
- No clue why you added the "php code too", to this question. Since your html code shows that the `<a>` should link to the "product homepage url" and not to product-detail.php?product_id={ID}